# React 18.2 TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'P.current.useState') in Safari 16

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to run locally my react app but getting an error [see screenshoot]

just doing simple return Text component

[image]

any can help what happen it's my code or react doest support it?